# Where did the Magento Code Migration Toolkit go?

Tags: migration, code-migration

I'm migrating a site from Magento 1 to Magento 2. I have a few custom extensions that I want to move over. The [Magento 2.4 documentation](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/migration/bk-migration-guide.html) links to a ["code migration toolkit" on github](https://github.com/magento/code-migration), however, that page gives a 404 and I cannot find this anywhere else. Was the Code Migration Toolkit deleted recently for some reason, and if so, should I be using a different method as my starting place for migrating over Magento 1 extensions?

Comment: Do you found any solution for this?

Comment: Unfortunately no

Answer (score 0):

You can try:
[Code Migration Toolkit](https://github.com/cpartica/code-migration) ,
[Convertm1m2](https://github.com/unirgy/convertm1m2)